# Scene in Material Preview, Rendered + Shading tab is completely black

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, shaders

First week on blender, sorry i'm being stupid

I was practicing re-creating a scene, and wanted to mess around with some colors, but I couldn't even in Material Properties and the Shading tab. Meshes don't even change color with the Base Color slider in Material Properties [ -1- ] or in the shading tab [ -2-] Only changes color when I change the RGB for the "Emission" Panel in Material Properties. [-3-]

I spent wayy too long on this, would love some help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when this happens, your Scene World lighting is turned on.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work https://prnt.sc/ZDNpY7ZZjISA

Comment: @snowflake Usually you would use _Scene Lights_ and _Scene World_ in _Rendered View_, if you turn them on are the objects then showing colors? Do you have lights or at least a world background to light the scene? It looks like you have set the _Strength_ to 0 in _Material Preview_ mode (especially in your second screenshot in the question where the preview spheres are black), but then the Strength in the _Rendered_ tab would be shown as 0, too... it's strange. Maybe you should upload a file (a simple cube in the scene should be sufficient).

Comment: aand how do yo upload a file? ._. I deeply apologize, it's probably something really stupid that isn't clicking in my brain. If you don't mind, how do I upload a file? And I appreciate the help, thank you so much >.<

Comment: @snowflake Use this website > [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and follow the instructions there. After successfully uploading your file you get some html code which you can add to your question by editing it. Or upload it here [pasteall.org/blend](https://pasteall.org/blend/) and paste the link in your question. The first link is more for permanently providing the file, the other is a temporary link which might be deleted in a few months.

Comment: Hey, @snowflake. I don't know if you've found a solution for this but I actually came across this same problem yesterday while working. The problem seems to be the viewport. You can remove the current viewport you have and make a new one by clicking and dragging the edge of the viewport. Same as creating a new viewport on-screen. Then you can just replace the old broken viewport with the new one.

Comment: @gjove https://prnt.sc/c_0BSTEpL_vd unfortunately still doesn't work >.< thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Just had to add a source of light and I was able to see color in the Rendered view. It's still all black in Material preview, but it's fine. I can work with that. Thank you for your suggestions. https://prnt.sc/yg-ChONITvD9